# list from list template doesn't get its custom view

Tags: custom-form, list-template

in C#/VS2013 I created a List Template with a custom view, set as default.
An event receiver creates a new List based on that List Template, but the newly created List doesn't use the custom view.

That view is available as "template view" when I enter the "Create view" page.
Indeed, how can I set a view in a List Template as default view for a List?